# How to smooth my line on a graph with 2 y axis in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I have a graph with 2 y axis that I've plotted a bar graph and a line graph on. The line graph has 1 value for each month, but I want to smooth the line graph, while still maintaining the 2 y axis. When I use the function `loess` it doesn't work for graphs with 2 y axis, and `spline` gives me completely different values than my original values.

Here some sample data similar to what I have:

```
month_new = month.abb
Temp = sample(25, 12)
mapoc_temp = cbind(month_new, Temp)

num_unique_tags = sample(25, 12)
month = month.abb
bargraph_dets_temp = cbind(month, num_unique_tags)
```

and I 've used the following code to graph this data

```
ggplot(bargraph_dets_temp, 
       aes(x = month, y = num_unique_tags)) +
  #for my detection data
  geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
  #For my temperature data
  geom_line(inherit.aes = FALSE, data = mapoc_temp,
            aes(x = month_new, y = as.numeric(Temp) + 2, group = 2),
            color = "forestgreen", size = 2) +
  #Make sure the 2 graphs share the same x axis
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")) +
  #putting 2 y scales on one graph
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,30), name = "Total Unique Detections", 
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . -2 , name = "Temperature (°C)"))
```

The picture it gives me looks like this

[image]

I don't care about the level of detail for the line graph I just want to show a general pattern of increasing and decreasing values, does anyone know how to make the line look smoother?

Comment: Try `geom_xspline` from the `ggalt` package instead of `geom_line`

Comment: will that still work with the rest of my ggplot stuff?

Comment: Have you try `geom_smooth` instead of `geom_line` ? (https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_smooth.html). By default, it's using `loess`.

Comment: Ok, I'm now realizing that maybe I need more data points to smooth it. I only have 1 value for each month, will smoothing work here?

Comment: I won't be really nice but you can try. Also, I'm not sure `geom_smooth` will work with discrete vlaues, so maybe you will need to concert tyour data in a date format

Comment: Hey. I am downvoting because this question is not reducing the problem to the core - it contains a lot of unnecessary code and this is a problem, because it is taking our time to read and understand and also shows lack of research into the problem. Please read [the guidance how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the part about a minimal reproducible example. In my own experience, when boiling down the code to the very core of the problem, the question often answers itself and you have even learned more from it then just by asking others

Comment: @Tjebo is this betteR?

Comment: It looks better, yet is still not reproducible. The point is, in order to really help, a concise and reproducible example is key. You could (and should!) try to reproduce your problem with a different data set which resembles your data. Best to use inbuilt data sets, but you can also create data frames, in your case you only need three columns, one categorical representing your months, then the bar and the line variables. It requires a bit of effort, but in the long run you'll learn much more from it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to interpolate the data you have with a spline. The first thing you should realize is that `month` and `month_new` are treated as numerics with values `1:12` by `ggplot`. But your way of plotting a discrete x-axis with custom limits causes trouble. Instead, to have better control of this mapping you should code your discrete x-values as a factor with a given order on its levels:

```
plot_data <- data.frame(month = factor(month.abb, levels = month.abb), 
                        temp = sample(25, 12),
                        num_unique_tags = sample(25, 12))
```

You can plot your data

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = month, y = num_unique_tags)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  geom_line(aes(y = temp, group = 2), color = "forestgreen", size = 2) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 30), name = "Total Unique Detections", 
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . -2 , name = "Temperature (°C)"))
```

To interpolate, you just make a new dataset with interpolated data and plot that:

```
plot_data_interp <- as.data.frame(spline(x = 1:12, y = plot_data$temp, xout = seq(1, 12, length = 100)),
                               col.names = c('month', 'temp'))

ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = month, y = num_unique_tags)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  geom_line(aes(y = temp, group = 2), data = plot_data_interp, color = "forestgreen", size = 2) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 30), name = "Total Unique Detections", 
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . -2 , name = "Temperature (°C)"))
```

And if you want to smooth data, you can do that (e.g. with a smoothing spline):

```
plot_data_smooth <- as.data.frame(predict(smooth.spline(x = 1:12, y = plot_data$temp, spar = 0.5), x = seq(1, 12, length = 100)),
                                  col.names = c('month', 'temp'))

ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = month, y = num_unique_tags)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  geom_line(aes(y = temp, group = 2), data = plot_data_smooth, color = "forestgreen", size = 2) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 30), name = "Total Unique Detections", 
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . -2 , name = "Temperature (°C)"))
```

The results are as follows:

[image]

Comment: why is it ```length = 100```?... also, if my mapoc_temp dataframe had a 3rd column with years and it was a total of 3 years, so therefore 36 months would ```x = 1:36``` and then ```seq(1, 36... ```?

Comment: The length 100 is just to make more points and thus show the smooth interpolating curve.

Comment: I have the data in 2 different dataframes. The data I provided are just samples. My dataframes have a different amount of variables. Is there a way to do this without combining the dataframes for ```temp``` and ```num_unique_dets```

Comment: @KristenCyr Both the interpolation and smoothing example actually makes a new dataset (`plot_data_interp` and `plot_data_smooth`), so you should just interpolate/smooth the data in `mapoc_temp` and put that in `plot_data_interp`/`plot_data_smooth`. The important thing is to construct your `month` variable as a factor with the `levels` argument giving the correct order of your values (if you have multiple years e.g. `levels = c('Dec 2017', 'Jan 2018', ..., 'Dec 2019')`. Your interpolation/smoothing should then use `x=1:lenght(bargraph_dets_temp$month)` as x-values for the spline functions.